# How to select all the pdfs containing a particular word?

Tags: windows, pdf, search, pdf-reader

I have 5000 pdfs out of which 500 pdfs are important, rest are useless. There is one word present in each 500 file that is not present in other 4500 files. I did multiple file search and came to know that I cannot select the 500 pdfs from the search result in Adobe Reader. Is there any other way to select multiple PDF files that contain a particular word?

Comment: The PDFs contains only words and no Images

Comment: Is there any uniformity among the PDFs? Are the page counts consistent? Are they all the same form, just filled out with unique information? Does the keyword appear in the same place in each of the 500 hits? If so, you could combine them all into one giant PDF then crop the pages to contain just the area that may or may not contain the keyword. This would leave you with a much more manageable pool of text in which the page numbers would correspond to the unaltered files. You might even be able to export it to Excel to determine it that way.

Comment: When you say "multiple file search," are you referring to the advanced search function in Reader (Ctrl+Alt+F)?

Comment: Could you provide us with some background about how the PDF's where generated?  You could use a tool like pdfTK to decode and break apart the PDF's if they where generated from Text documents directly.

Comment: What happens when you look at your PDF's in notepad?  Can you search through the text document with notepad's find feature?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/402673/how-to-search-inside-pdfs-with-windows-search

Answer (score 1):

You have three main options

Option one:

Get your 5000 pdfs. Make 10 folders of 500. Run 10 individual searches.

Option two:

Windows search (definitely 10, not sure on others but worth a shot) works through PDF files. Just go to your folder, type in your keyword, all the relevant files should be returned.

Option three:

Libraries like iTextSharp would allow you to get the text from a document in something like C#. You can loop through all the documents and do what you need with them, assuming you are able to use C#.

Apparently FoxIt reader gives a similar search through folder function - I don't know if this is limited to 500 also though.

Comment: It should be noted that all these options require that the PDF be parsable/searchable. Many PDFs are not, especially those that originated from a  scanned document without high quality OCR. If you can select text with your mouse, then the doc should work, but if you cannot select discrete words, then the document is unsearchable. A few years ago, I had to create a document repository, with indexing, so we used PDFBox with IKVM.Net  to pull the text for indexing, but we had to print and rescan many of the documents; otherwise they were like a picture of the original.

Comment: Yes, sorry, blindly assumed the text was actual text and not an image or odd encoding. This comment is definitely important, if the documents are scans, without clever OCR software, you'll be out of luck.

Comment: (I think) Newer versions of Adobe reader have OCR built into them, so they search through PDF's that are only composed of embedded images, which is what every scan-to-pdf system that I have seen does (HP, Konica-Minolta, Canon, Kryocera, Epson).  I have certainly been able to search the Image based PDF's at work generated by our Konica Scanners, and the PDF's are only embedded JPG's when viewed by Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0):

I've been solving the very same problem with how to search through thousands of PDF files and work with those which contained a particular string. [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/download.htm) with [xPDFSearch](http://totalcmd.net/plugring/xpdfsearch.html) plugin did the trick for me. The plugin enhances the Total Commander's search capabilities to allow searching through PDF meta tags or to do even a fulltext search.

Total Commander is available also as Shareware, but if you like it please contribute to the author of this brilliant manager.

Comment: Please consider adding more information about how the softwares you recommended can solve OP's question, and short summary of what they do. For more information : https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers

Comment: Are you, by any chance, the author of Total Commander, or a close friend, relative, or associate?  Because if you are, you must say so.

Comment: @Vylix I've extended the answer a bit, hopefully correctly.

Comment: @Scott I am in no relation to the author, I just genuinely love the software, been using it for more than a decade.