# Command line that searches within file content and automatically renames file when specific term is found

Tags: command-line, powershell, pdf, rename

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a command that would search the contents of a file, then rename said file with the specific term that was found. Ideally, this would be run at a subfolder from powershell and batch rename all the files within the folder.

To showcase my specific example; I have a folder containing 100+ pdf files, each with a generic name. I have to open each file individually to get the title and then rename it as such. As you can all imagine, it is a very manual process that I would like to streamline with a command.

All comments are welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
RM

Comment: For this to be possible, the PDFs must contain metadata, especially title. Otherwise, it's impossible.

Comment: If you're interested in doing this with PDFs, have a look at this [Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1278479/302907).