# Find files by contents (Windows 11)

Tags: windows-explorer, pdf, windows-search, windows-11, file-search

I'm trying to search through 15 years of bank statements (PDF) for a specific payment amount, $42.69. I used Windows explorer file search (bar in upper right corner of file explorer) in the folder containing the statement files, and searched `content:42.69`. The search returned no results.

I am not convinced that that amount does not exist, so I tested the search function with a known amount `202.93` taken from a file in the folder I was searching. When I view the file in my PDF reader and use the reader's such function, it finds the `202.93` text string.

In Windows explorer file search, when I searched `content:202.93` in the same folder, I get no results.

In Windows explorer file search, when I searched `content:202` in the same folder, it found three other statements but not the one I was expecting. The statements it found all did contain the string "202", but not finding the one I was looking for is clearly a problem; I can't trust a result that no file is found as being proof that the string does not exist in any files.

I've reviewed the indexing options for PDFs in Control Panel -> Indexing Options -> Advanced Options -> File Types. I ensured that they are set to the proper setting for PDFs: using "Reader Search Handler" and "Index Properties and File Contents".

That said, the files may not be getting indexed at all. I have them saved in my OneDrive folder so I have cloud access. When I go into Control Panel -> Indexing Options -> Modify, my OneDrive folder isn't listed and it's not showing up in its spot under the C: drive (C:\Users). From searches on that issue, it appears to be expected behavior so I guess Windows doesn't index the OneDrive folder for searching. That's not ideal, but using the `content:` tag should, I believe, force it to search contents and find the file I'm looking for. But again as described above that's not working for me.

Any suggestions on how to resolve? I am not married to a solution of Windows built-in search. I just need some way on my Windows 11 machine that will properly search through all files (including PDFs) in a folder and return all files with a text string, even if that string is a number with decimal point.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search inside PDFs with Windows Search?](https://superuser.com/questions/402673/how-to-search-inside-pdfs-with-windows-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me ages to find the solution. It seems to be a problem with the Windows or the Adobe PDF plugin.
Use regedit.exe to make sure that for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf\PersistentHandler` the `(Default)` value points to the Windows PDF Persistent Handler `{1AA9BF05-9A97-48c1-BA28-D9DCE795E93C}`.

Then go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\PluginResourceData\{6C337B26-3E38-4F98-813B-FBA18BAB64F5}` and make sure that `PenaltyBox` is set to 0.

If it is set to 3, PDF search is switched off. Go to "services.msc", switch off "Windows Search", set `Penalty Box` to 0, then restart the "Windows Search" service. Make sure that `Penalty Box` remains 0 (press F5 in regedit.exe).

It might help creating a new DWORD `ShutoffThreshold` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\PluginResourceData` and set it to hex `ffffffff` if the problem occurs again. This was not necessary on all computers.

Comment: Amazing, you fixed it! I'm now searching PDFs again. One clarification: after you do all this, you should rebuild the index (Indexing Options -> Advanced -> Rebuild). Before I rebuilt the index, it was only finding PDFs I had opened since I did the "PenaltyBox" thing. Full rebuild resolved that.